# ImageMagic resize and accidental redirection

Tags: php, bash, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick to generate an image thumbnail, and i'm experiencing a weird problem.  Weird because this *has* worked before and I dunno what changed to make it start failing.

Anyway, my commandline looks like this: (except that I've simplified the filenames)

```
convert -size 160x160 a1.jpg -thumbnail 144x144 -bordercolor #F00 -border 160-gravity center -crop 160x160+0+0 -repage -format jpg -quality 70 ./a2.jpg
```

What's happening is that the system is redirecting to a file named " -bordercolor"

Any ideas why this is happening and how to avoid?

Comment: You do know there is PHP extension called Imagick? You should use that instead of cli calls to imagemagick.

Comment: The code uses Imagick when it's available but it's not in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

On bash everything after the ***#*** will be considered part of a commment.

Maybe enclosuring the color with quotes

Comment: That might be correct about the comment idea but it doesn't explain the redirection.

Comment: Well, Imagemagick command will assume that the last argument is the output path to the operation then, I guess that it should explain why a file named "-bordercolor" is being created.

Comment: The redirect part is a little bit strange.. Since you tagged "php", are you using php to call a shell that call ImageMagick?

Comment: Just using the system() function but I got same result when I wrote the command out to an SH script and ran that in the shall.

Comment: on the `-border 160-gravity` part it seems that you are missing a space between the `160` and `-gravity` probably what made your command to not do what you expected from it and leading you to try it on shell where the ***#*** lead to the "-bordercolor"  file

Comment: This is working now... The weird thing about all this is that this code was working before, and all of a sudden all these little things are wrong with it.  I need to step through GIT history and see if something got changed at some point and I wasn't aware of it.